# Clarification: How can I deploy my app in cloudbees (react-native app) using fastlane (Need steps for fastlane cloudbees setup)

Tags: android, ios, deployment, fastlane, cloudbees

Clarification: How can I deploy my app in cloudbees (react-native app) using fastlane

I need to know the steps for fastlane cloudbees setup.

But the fastlane documentation is not available for cloudbees setup.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/continuous-integration/appcircle/